# Tailwind css not rendering tailwind ui components properly using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I am using tailwind css along with tailwind ui's prebuilt components for rails 7 project.

I installed tailwind as per their ruby on rails guide - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/ruby-on-rails

Some of the utility classes seem to be working. Like i can change the colour of my nav links using the utilty classes but whenver I try to copy some of the prebuilt components from tailwind ui, it does not render correctly

This is what the body of my application should look like
[image: What it should like]

This is what it currently looks like
[image: This is my current application]

These are some of my files below
my **application.tailwind.css**

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";

@import "tailwindcss/components";


@import "tailwindcss/utilities";



/*

@layer components {
  .btn-primary {
    @apply py-2 px-4 bg-blue-200;
  }
}

*/
```

my **config/tailwind.css**

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/views/**/*',
    './app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Inter var', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/container-queries'),
  ]
}
```

my **application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Kickconnect</title>
    <%# <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous"> %>

    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "tailwind", "inter-font", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>


    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
  </head>

  <body class="prose mx-auto" >
    <%= render partial:'home/newheader' %>
   
    <div class=>
    <%=notice%> 
     <%= yield %>
    </div>
    
    <%# <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've pretty much tried everything to get it to work but it wont render properly. I tried running './bin/dev.', doesnt change a thing

Comment: @Alex the tailwind ui components is just regular html code styled using tailwind css, rather than writing your own components from scratch. I do not need to include them in my tailwind.config as they are all just in regular .html.erb files.

Comment: @Alex i removed the stylesheet_link_tag "application" and included utilities and it still isnt working

Comment: "ui components is just regular html code" - i get that. however, you can only use it if it is part of `content` config, so if you're using it in your regular views, you're good. run `bin/rails assets:clobber` if you have precompiled any assets in development, i've seen people do that for some reason a lot. run `bin/dev` you should see `css    | Rebuilding...` then make a change in one of your files and see if you get "Rebuilding.." again

Comment: omg the bin/rails assets:clobber worked! thank you so much! If you dont mind, can you explain what was wrong?

Comment: @alex also if you post your comment as a reply to the original post i can accept it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precompiled assets do not change when you make changes to your files. `bin/rails assets:precompile` is for production, you don't need to run it in development. `bin/rails assets:clobber` removes precompiled assets.

---

The rest are details you probably don't need, but are useful to know:

`bin/dev` is equivalent to:

```rb
# bin/dev

foreman start -f Procfile.dev
```

That will start your rails server and tailwind watcher that compiles your css on any file change:

```rb
# Procfile.dev

web: bin/rails server
css: bin/rails tailwindcss:watch[debug]
```

The `css:` part just goes through rails and runs a rake [task](https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/blob/v2.0.30/lib/tasks/build.rake#L11) from `tailwindcss-rails` gem which in turn runs the underlying tailwind command:

```bash
tailwindcss -w -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/tailwind.css -c config/tailwing.config.js
```

Which is why you're including `stylesheet_link_tag "tailwind"` in your layout and not "application".

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/tailwind-9c64e6c4285db52078d6a7537e9e32ee60f6d54c2e68fea533ea2b196e6c8aa9.css" data-turbo-track="reload">
```

There are two places this request ^ could be handled. First is `ActionDispatch::Static` middleware (see `bin/rails middleware`) which servers files from `public` directory. These assets take priority and will be served first. Second is `sprockets` engine, which is mounted in your routes.

`bin/rails assets:precompile` - you only do this for production deployment. It will compile all of your assets and put them in `public/assets` (these should be handled by your webserver, eg nginx). Files in `public/assets` do not update when you make changes to your files, unless you run precompile again.

`bin/rails assets:clobber` - just removes `public/assets` directory.

Now that you don't have that directory, your asset requests can hit `sprockets` engine which will compile assets on the fly and serve new and updated assets. This way when you make changes, your assets are always updated, in this case it is the updated `tailwind.css` file.

Also to be clear `app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css` is first compiled by tailwind to do the tailwind magic, then `app/builds/tailwind.css` is picked up by `sprockets` to hook it into rails lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

you can run the following command on your terminal :

```
rails tailwindcss:build
```

that works for me.